# Mongoose : How to display in the console the content of an Object typed Mixed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

with the following **data** :

```
lines: [{ line: [12, 'Joe'] }, { line: [14, 'John'] }, { line: [6, 'Walter'] }, { line: [3, 'William'] }, { line: [18, 'Bill'] }, { line: [22, 'Albert'] }]
```

and the **Model**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Line = new Schema({
  line: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lines: [Line]
});
```

when I save then display the collection in the console I get :
**console.log**

```
res.body: { __v: 0,
  _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf4e',
  lines: 
   [ { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf54', line: [Object] },
     { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf53', line: [Object] },
     { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf52', line: [Object] },
     { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf51', line: [Object] },
     { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf50', line: [Object] },
     { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf4f', line: [Object] } ],
```

should not it be ?

```
   [ { _id: '590437516c71e30ee4ddcf54', line: [12, 'Joe']
   ...
```

why the content of the inner Array Object is not fully displayed ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is too deeply nested for `console.log()`, which, under the hood, uses [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to inspect objects. The default recursion depth for that function is 2.

To increase the depth to "infinity", you can use this:

```
console.log(util.inspect(data, { depth : null }));
```

Alternatively, you can make `console.log()` output JSON:

```
console.log('%j', data);
```